# Error in Serial communication Mathematica

Tags: serial

I have a problem with serial communication in Mathematica. This is related to byte 'FF'. Whenever a byte 'FF' is received via serial port, there will be two bytes of 'FF' in the serial buffer, thus resulting in wrong number of received bytes. 
I tried to read the serial data with a small python code and there was no such error.
I am using Mathematica  10.3 and Raspberry Pi 3. How can I fix this problem? Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is from 3 years ago, but for anyone else that stumbles upon this question: I reported this issue to Mathematica a few weeks ago, and they confirmed it as a bug and handed it off to the developers. My ticket has been closed as "It's in the hands of the Devs now" so hopefully I can revisit this issue soon to confirm the issue is resolved.

EDIT: Case number is 4362269

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add the case number to your answer.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi understood, added.